# linux - show image on console / X11

Tags: x11, console, video

Is it possible to show an arbitrary image across the console / X11?  In essence, I just want the video output to be the image.  Is there a way to do that?

I would want the console virtual terminals to be disabled as well as X11, so I'd like to just display an image through the video driver some how.  I can disable the console and X11, but don't know how to load an image.

Thanks,

Walter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `fbida` ?

https://www.kraxel.org/blog/linux/fbida/

Under [this](https://superuser.com/questions/495948/can-i-display-a-jpg-or-png-to-the-framebuffer-dev-fb) discussion there appears to sometimes be a `-noverbose` option to display **just** the image without a status bar.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out - this looks promising as I'll have to control the framebuffer and that is what I was expecting.

Comment: That is perfect.  Now, I just need to see what more I can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i've already researched it and all answers were NO YOU CAN'T.

Maximum i get was installing imagemagick package via apt-get install imagemagick command and running display imagefile.jpg, but under X11.